# How to create a prepared statement to replace mysqli_query?

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I am trying to turn this section of SQL query into a prepared statement but it has related functions calling its results so am having a hard time tying it all up so here is

This is the SQL statement:

```
{
    $name = explode(' ', $key, 2); // Break String into Array.

    if(empty($name[1])) {
        $sql = "SELECT * 
                FROM users 
                WHERE users.user_firstname = '$name[0]' 
                OR users.user_lastname= '$name[0]'";

    } else {
        $sql = "SELECT * 
                FROM users 
                WHERE users.user_firstname = '$name[0]' 
                AND users.user_lastname= '$name[1]'";
    }

    include 'includes/userquery.php';
}
```

The functions calling it:

```
$query = mysqli_query($conn, $sql); 
if(mysqli_num_rows($query) == 0){
    echo '<div class="post">';
    echo 'There is no results given the keyword, try to widen your search query.';
    echo '</div>';
    echo '<br>';
}

while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query)){
    include 'includes/post.php';
    echo '<br>';
}
```

I tried some ways of turning the query into prepared but I get errors such as ? placeholder isn't identified or functions receiving bool

Comment: Too much white space in code just makes it unreadable

Comment: *I tried some ways of turning the query into prepared* ... Can we see your prepared statement attempt?

Comment: Your question is a little too broad. Are you asking how to get `mysqli_result` from prepared statement or are you asking how to use placeholders in PS?

Comment: this particular problem has nothing to do with prepared statements: in the end you have just two variables that can be bound in the either case. But the thing is, [you could have simplified your condition even before](https://phpize.online/sql/mysql57/undefined/php/php81/c4407177ccd3271e4cf05a619a6a2996/), as the difference between both branches is minimal. It's about programming, not prepared statements

Comment: @Dharman I am asking how to turn the $sql into a prepared statement without messing its connection with $query, sorry for confusion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simplify the whole process if you start by loading 2 vars before starting the query with the right values from your `$name` array.

Then a simple change to the query to make it parameterised and bindable will allow you to prepare, bind and execute the query

Then a small change to the fetching process should have you off and running

```
{
    $name = explode(' ', $key, 2); // Break String into Array.

    if(empty($name[1])) {
        $n1 = $name[0];
        $n2 = $name[0];
        $sql = "SELECT * 
                FROM users 
                WHERE users.user_firstname = ? 
                OR users.user_lastname= ?";
    } else {
        $n1 = $name[0];
        $n2 = $name[1];
        $sql = "SELECT * 
                FROM users 
                WHERE users.user_firstname = ? 
                AND users.user_lastname= ?";
    }


    $stmt = $conn->prepare($sql);
    $stmt->bind_param('ss', $n1,$n2);
    $result = $stmt->execute();
    $query = $stmt->get_result();
    
    include 'includes/userquery.php';
}
```

The function (I assume thats whats being included) would then become

```
if($query->num_rows == 0){
    echo '<div class="post">';
    echo 'There is no results given the keyword, try to widen your search query.';
    echo '</div>';
    echo '<br>';
}

while($row = $query->fetch_assoc()){
    include 'includes/post.php';
    echo '<br>';
}
```

Comment: @YourCommonSense Is the downvote because of the _Unexplained issue with a redundant piece of code_? If so, please explain what bit of code

Comment: "You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near '? OR users.user_lastname= ?'"

I met this error in my earlier tries too, do you know why? seems this is the only error right now

Comment: It could be a simple lack of a space between `?` and `OR` so try `WHERE users.user_firstname = ? OR users.user_lastname= ?`

Comment: Usaually the error message contains more detail than you show, can you show the complete error message

Answer (score 0):

They way you use include is non-standard, usually includes are done at the top of file, only when the included files returns something its called in middle of code, this way its like copy pasting code to specific block, which does work but it cause confusion like you have variable `$sql` in `includes/userquery.php` but from where does it come from ? its not defined in that file and not even included, ofc now when you writing your code you know but later no way you will remember. Its way better to use functions which you include on top of file then call at place you want the functionality and pass data as parameters, that way its clear whats going on. Now lets see what you can do with your current code:

```php
{
    $name = explode(' ', $key, 2); // Break String into Array.

    if(empty($name[1])) {
        $sql_param_types = 'ss';
        $sql_params = [$name[0], $name[0]];
        $sql = "SELECT * 
                FROM users 
                WHERE users.user_firstname = ? 
                OR users.user_lastname= ?";

    } else {
        $sql_param_types = 'ss';
        $sql_params = [$name[0], $name[1]];
        $sql = "SELECT * 
                FROM users 
                WHERE users.user_firstname = ?
                AND users.user_lastname= ?";
    }

    include 'includes/userquery.php';
}
```

userquery.php:

```php
$stmt = mysqli_prepare($conn, $sql);
$stmt->bind_param($sql_param_types, ...$sql_params);
$stmt->execute();
$result = $stmt->get_result();

if($result->num_rows == 0){
    echo '<div class="post">';
    echo 'There is no results given the keyword, try to widen your search query.';
    echo '</div>';
    echo '<br>';
}

while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()){
    include 'includes/post.php';
    echo '<br>';
}
```

Comment: Sorry about the includes part, I didnt realize it matters here because essentially the include files rely on the $query there so as long as it functions I thought it would be fine.
Anyway, I will try your remake of the code soon if it functions with the main parts

Comment: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near '? OR users.user_lastname= ?'

I met this error in my earlier tries too, do you know why? seems this is the only error right now

Comment: @Zero seems like you did not call `$stmt->bind_param`